# using java how to send a mail without authentication

Tags: java, email

I set following property to send a mail to gmail without authenticating but i am not able to send. please help me

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTPServer);
//props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTPPort);
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'not able to send'?. do you get any error?

Comment: What error or exception are you getting? What is `SMTPServer`? Do you (or your company) own it?

Comment: smtp server is smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Error message: [Cannot send email. javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1

Comment: I think gmail.com doesn't allow send mail without authentificantion

Comment: Why don't you want to authenticate?

Comment: this is my project so i don't want to authenticate

Comment: You don't have the choice, unless you can find a mail server that doesn't require it. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) port 465 is ssl port, therefore you need create SSL connection (you comment this string)

```
//props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
```

2) I'm sure that smtp.gmail.com doesn't allow connection without authentification, because everybody could send mail from any user....
**edit:**
And check telnet to smtp.gmail.com 465

look at the article for sending mail
http://www.journaldev.com/2532/java-program-to-send-email-using-smtp-gmail-tls-ssl-attachment-image-example